# In Sublime Text, Gedit or any Other editor, how to select and replace everything inside Tags?

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2, gedit

I have a database backup of a wordpress file. I need to replace all the captions with a div. I need to replace the whole caption tag `[caption id="dfdsf"]` and the closing tag `[/caption]` (with the braces) with a div. How can I do this? Replacing the closing tag will be easy. But searching for the opening tag is difficult because there could be anything inside it! How to do this?

Here's an example :

```
[caption id="attachment_34552" align="aligncenter" width="550"]<img class="size-large wp-image-34552" alt="Octopress" src="http://....jpg" width="550" height="385" /> Octopress [/caption]
```

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: @JustinL. Its :  <div class="sss"><img class="size-large wp-image-34552" alt="Octopress" src="http://....jpg" width="550" height="385" /> Octopress </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind regexes, the regex that matches the opening is

```
/\[caption[^]]*\]/
```

http://rubular.com/r/eRRxYIsVCG

remember to specify case insensitivity if you're going to have `caption` and `CAPTION`, etc.

if you just want to do this on the command line you can use `sed(1)`

```
sed 's/\[caption[^]]*\]/<div class=\\"sss\\">/g' file.html
```

which sends it to stdin, which you can pipe to whatever file you want.

if you want to modify the file in-place you can add the `-i` switch to `sed`.

Comment: Is there a different tool (even a command line tool) to do this? Sublime gets stuck.

Comment: you can use `sed(1)` on a unix machine (i've updated my answer to show how), but i'm sure sublime has something you can configure to let it work.

Comment: Everything works except for one tiny problem... The SQL file have " signs escaped. For example, <div class=\"mceTemp mceIEcenter\" > How to add this \?

Comment: you can just add the `\` into the replace expression (i updated the answer to reflect this), but remember that because you're in bash you'll have to escape the `\` and write `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the expand selection command. It's `ctrl+shift+m` in Windows and Linux. I can't recall the OS X bindings off the top of my head. You can see the binding for it by selection the `Selection` menu if you are unsure (assuming you haven't overridden it yet). Place the cursor somewhere within the square braces. The first expansion will not include the square braces, but the second will.

Comment: A regex would probably work as Justin said. But you could use multi cursor functionality in ST, combined with the expand selection to take care of them all at once. Up to you though.

Comment: Oh also, depending on the format of the file, you could also use the "Wrap Selection with Tag" command to quickly wrap your stuff in divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed from the terminal in a unix machine.

The command would be like

```
sed "s/\[caption \([^]]*\)\]/<div \1>/g" youdata.txt > file.txt 
sed "s/\[/caption\]/</div>/g" file.txt > file.txt
```

Comment: If I need to add a class to the div, is this correct : sed "s/\[caption \([^]]*\)\]/<div class="imgcap" \1>/g" youdata.txt > file.txt

Comment: Yes. You can use sed -i if you want to replace directly in the file and not create a new file.